# Select nested elements by name attribute javascript(no jquery)

Tags: javascript, html

So I have this HTML code and I need to select the elements by their name attribute. The problem is I have multiple elements with the same structure and I need to go throw them with a loop.

```
<div class="res">
    <h4 name="title">title</h4>
    <span name="span1"></span>
    <span name="span2"></span>
    <p name="p1"></p>
    <p name="p2"></p>
</div>
```

I need to select each one of the elements inside the .res div element by their name(or if there's a better solution I'd like to you).

Comment: i tried to access it by using document.getElementsByClassName("res")[0].title cuz i thought it would work like adding a full path and forgot that this one is used for the attributes, so i did some googling and found nothing helpfull. so i'm clearly have the wrong approache and i don't know what to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the DOM Element.children attribute in pure javascript

```
var children = res.children;
for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
  var child = children[i];
  // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: didn't know about the children function, thanks for the new information :D

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementsByName("res");
document.getElementsByName("title");
document.getElementsByName("span");
```

or you can loop through the elements if you don't want to hard-code the name.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.querySelector()` like :

```
document.querySelector('[name="xxxxxx"]');
```

If you want to loop through all the `res` containers you could use `.querySelctorAll()` like :

```
var containers = document.querySelectorAll('.res');

for( var i = 0; i < containers.length; i++) {
    console.log( containers[i].querySelector('[name="title"]').textContent );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `querySelectorAll` and inside loop handle every element.

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".res > *");

elements.forEach(element => {
  console.log(element);
});
```

```html
<div class="res">
    <h4 name="title">title</h4>
    <span name="span1"></span>
    <span name="span2"></span>
    <p name="p1"></p>
    <p name="p2"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: i'm using multiple divs so i'll need to go throw each one seperately